# Using many different html page with express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am learning node js/express and had a quick question. Is it bad to use mulitple different html files for your get method in express. For example, for each of the get methods, I am opening a different html file.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var html = fs.readFileSync('index2.html');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(html);
});


app.get('/continuous', function(req, res){
  var html = fs.readFileSync('index6.html');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(html);
});

app.get('/output', function(req, res){
  var html = fs.readFileSync('index4.html');
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(html);
});
```

Comment: That is fine but why are you using `fs` here ? Just `res.sendFile(PATH)` will do...

Comment: Ohh okay thank you, fs is just what I found in a tutorial but will use res.sendFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `res.sendFile` to make that process easier:

```
app.get('/game', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/game.html', {
        root: path.join(__dirname, '/public')
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Althought not *always* useful, slugs are pretty great.

```
app.get('/:page', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + req.params + ".html");
});
```

A request to `localhost/some-page` would return the file `some-page.html` from the same directory.

Beware of not doing this in the same directory as sensitive data.